# Does reconnectFailed event still exist in Mongoose v5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dom-events

I found an [article](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.12-improved-connection-events.html) stating that the `reconnectFailed` is emitted by mongoose as of v4.12.

I'm using Mongoose v5.0.14 and I can't seem to find that event anywhere in the documentation, neither in the documentation for v4.13.

Does this event still exist?
If so, where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, version 5.0.14 still emits reconnectFailed when the underlying driver emits the same event.

lines 445 - 447 of node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:

```
  db.s.topology.on('reconnectFailed', function() {
    _this.emit('reconnectFailed');
  });
```

There isn't really much to document here other than the settings you provide the connection with, i.e. reconnectTries, reconnectInterval, etc.

Those [Connection options are here.](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect)

Basically, this event will be emitted when the mongodb native driver has attempted and failed to reconnect to the server after the number of times specified in your options as reconnectTries. If not specified the default value is 30 times with a 1 second wait between each attempt.

It's also worth noting that **reconnectFailed** will only ever be fired if you were connected successfully in the first place, and then failed to reconnect.